# Hashes not being removed from URL's after cancelling edit UI that needed them

Tags: feature-request, jobs, hyperlinks, cv

When I recently viewed my cv completeness page

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/score/[user number]
```

I clicked on

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/[user number]#section-objectives
```

then I clicked <kbd>cancel</kbd>, however it didn't remove the `#section-objectives` from the URL, which meant if I chose to refresh the page, the edit UI would become expanded again.

I think that <kbd>cancel</kbd> should also amend the URL, to prevent this (or bookmarked pages having this) problem.